# Tweet button enabled by default When Text is more than 280 characters in Twitter share extension

Tags: ios, swift, twitter

Tweet button enabled by default When Text is more than 280 characters in Twitter share extension.

Twitter can only tweet 280 characters.

Expected behaviour : Tweet button should be disabled by default if characters is more then 280

```
let shareText = delegate.shareText() // Text is more then 280 characters

if let shareURL = URL(string: url) 
var objectsToShare = [shareText, shareURL]

let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare as [AnyObject], applicationActivities: nil)
    if (activityVC.popoverPresentationController != nil) {
        activityVC.popoverPresentationController!.sourceView = shareButton
    }

    parentVC.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Read this https://github.com/shinobicontrols/iOS8-day-by-day/blob/master/02-sharing-extension/02-sharing-extension.md#validating-user-input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a programming-related question since it's neither your fault nor Apple's. Once upon a time, the Twitter share sheet was provided by the system, this, however, changed a few years ago.

Now, the share sheet is delivered in conjunction with Twitter's native iOS app, so if it doesn't do the button highlighting properly, it's a bug in their app and shouldn't be your worry. You can nonetheless contact them and ask them to fix it.